# How to save images to an external hard-drive ASP.Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin App, that I am using to create an Image and make an API call to Asp.net core which uploads it to Azure blob storage. However now I would like to save the image locally, to my external hard drive(using a Mac book) using Asp.net core web API. See below for my blob storage controller. Please help me modify it so I can save it locally (External hard-drive)

````
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm]IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                //foreach (var file in files)
                //{
                    var response = await _blobService.UploadBlobAsync(file.FileName, file, "containerName");
               // }

                return Ok(true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal server error");
            }
        }```
````

Comment: "local" to what?  To the server running your ASP.NET service?  Or local to the mobile app?  To save it locally to the server, just use `File.WriteAllBytes` or a similar method to save it to a filepath.

Comment: To a hard drive C:// but in my case Volumes/  I'm on a Mac not sure how to do that though

Comment: I just told you what to do.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0#methods

Answer (score 1):

As we know, we can [download the file from azure blob storage](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-blob-storage-uploaddownloaddelete-files-using-net-5/), and get Stream like below

```
Stream blobStream = blockBlob.OpenReadAsync().Result;
```

I think after we get the `blobStream`, then you need [set file permission to 644](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132081/file-permissions-on-linux-unix-with-net-core), then you can [save your file to specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117781/how-to-use-file-writeallbytes-of-c-sharp-to-write-on-mounted-drives).

**Related Post:**

[Find your external path in MacOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1192930/how-do-you-reference-a-file-on-an-external-drive-on-a-mac-from-a-script-command)